# SSL for Websphere connectionfactory in admin console

Tags: java, websphere

I want to enable SSL for my Connectionfactory which I created in Websphere admin console. How can I create a SSL Connection between Websphere Application Server and Java Client? Can I use the admin console? Should I create key and truststores? Is there any good guide which I can use?

This is my code:

`Hashtable prop = new Hashtable(); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809"); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, User); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Password); InitialContext Ctxt = new InitialContext(prop); ConnectionFactory ConFac = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) Ctxt.lookup("MyConnectionFactory");`

Now I receive the following errors:

javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible

and

java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine

Regardless of my Errors: How can someone create a SSL Connection between Websphere Application Server and Java Client?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far and what problems you encountered.

Comment: Hashtable<String, Serializable> prop = new Hashtable<String, Serializable>();
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, User);
prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Password);

InitialContext Ctxt = new InitialContext(prop);

ConnectionFactory ConFac = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) Ctxt.lookup("MyConnectionFactory");

Comment: I created a JMS-ConnectionFactory in the admin console with JNDI-Name "MyConnectionFactory". Then I got security Problems. I added System.setProperty("com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL", "path_to_file/sas.client.props"); in my code and I get the error: CWPKI0019E: error in the syntax analysis of the SSL-client configuration file path_to_file/sas.client.props error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: And now post that code in your answer with proper formatting so people can read it. :)

Comment: <code> Hashtable<String, Serializable> prop = new Hashtable<String, Serializable>(); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809"); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, User); prop.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, Password); InitialContext Ctxt = new InitialContext(prop); ConnectionFactory ConFac = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory) Ctxt.lookup("MyConnectionFactory"); </code>

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss typed. Please post your code in your question. :)

Comment: @user3692203: What Malloc is saying is that you should not post code as comments as you just did. You should edit your original question and add the code in there. it is much easier for you to format the code in the question  (than in the comments) and that will make it much easier for us all to read (and help you).

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? :)

Comment: Regardless of my Errors: How can someone create a SSL Connection between Websphere Application Server and Java Client?

Comment: Can anyone read my text? :)